# How do i make my windows command line more user friendly for running Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, window

I am new to RoR and am looking for a way, if possible, to make the Windows command line more user friendly like the mac system. Specifically an easier way to copy and paste, such as using short cut keys, but other suggestions are welcome to. So far I have managed to re-size the window and change the font and font size.

Please keep in mind that i am not technically proficient in this area and answers with steps would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download GitBash :D

Here's a link: [GitBash installation links and howto](https://openhatch.org/missions/windows-setup/install-git-bash)

It'll use bash instead of window's CLI, and makes stuff like GIT or SSH a breeze.

How to copy and paste the output of commands/files to clipboard with gitbash
[Link](https://coderwall.com/p/pmduxw)